# Which database to choose for user event logging

Tags: sql, mongodb, hadoop, ravendb, database

I am looking into finding the database that has the best fit for my current problem. 
I need to log user related events.  A bit like Google analytics. 
Whenever an event happens that relate to a customer I need to log what The event was. 
For example. 
The customer reads an article. 
I need to log. 
User info. 
Organisation info in which the user resides. 
Info about the article. (Id, how much was read, etc)
Time of event.

In other cases it could be something different but still relatively get to the the customer.
So the data is somewhat unstructured.

Later on Alle these events needs to be analyzed. 
Some for behaviour analysis other could be calculated how much the user should pay for the services in They have used.

There has to be some level of real time interaction with the system, f.ex. Having real time analytics running to see specific behaviour or other.

It should be able to handle at least one million events a day and also be able to have an index that holds data for 5 years. 
Events will be fairly small.

We are primarily a .NET house so a nice framework around the system that supports . NET would be nice.

I hope that someone has suggestions or can point me at some literature that reflects on my above scenario. I have looked quite a bit but have not found any really good docs about this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mongo does have good drivers for .NET and seems like a good choice: https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-log-data/

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the link. I had not found that use case for MongoDB.
It seems that MongoDB now has a connector to Apache Spark so doing real time analytics should be possible. https://www.mongodb.com/press/mongodb-enables-advanced-real-time-analytics-on-fast-moving-data-with-new-connector-for-apache-spark